# Generic Constraint with default in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using TypeScript 2.7.2 with Angular. I've been googling a while to know how we can specify default type for a generic constraint.

```
class BaseComponentModel {
}

class BaseComponent<T extends BaseComponentModel = BaseComponentModel> {

   @Input()
   public model: T;

}

class ButtonComponentModel {
}

class ButtonComponent extends BaseComponent<ButtonComponentModel> {
}
```

The above code is failing.

Comment: What error are you getting ? I tried and the code you posted works

Comment: I think the issue might be with WebStorm. It is using an older version of Typescript.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might be able to guess your error, but first things first; the code concerning generics is fine.

The error I guess you have is regarding experimental decorators, which you can suppress with your `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "experimentalDecorators": true
    }
}
```

Using this flag I get no errors, with the following mini-test app.

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/core": "6.0.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "2.7.2"
  }
}
```

*tsconfig.json*

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "experimentalDecorators": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

*app.ts*

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';

class BaseComponentModel {
}

class BaseComponent<T extends BaseComponentModel = BaseComponentModel> {

   @Input()
   public model: T;

}

class ButtonComponentModel {
}

class ButtonComponent extends BaseComponent<ButtonComponentModel> {
}
```